# C# Actions only calling last added action (With Dictionary)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've these two classes, the base class creates the dictionary and adds one item to it. The second class extends the first, and then trys to add some local functionality to the dictionary. When I do this, no matter which entry is called, the last added method will fire. Why is this? I believe the problem to be that I'm not adding local variables for the Action calls. I'd prefer avoiding this technique.

```
public class classA {

  Dictionary<string, Action> someDict = new Dictionary<string, Action>

  public classA() {
    someDict.Add("Foo", () => Foo());
  }

  void Foo() {
  ...
  }
}

public class classB : classA {
  public classB () {
    someDict.Add("Foo1", () => Foo1())
  }

  void Foo1() {
  ...
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're confusing an object instance with a class. Inheritance does nothing to merge discrete objects. If you're trying to build a collection, you need a single object which will hold that collection.

Comment: Yes that's correct thanks to you. Early morning brain farts!

Comment: Well, if an instance of classB would be created, its ``someDict`` would contain both entries: Foo and Foo1. An instance of classA would only contain Foo. But I don't get the last sentence of your question: "No matter which entry is called..." What do you mean by that? Can you give the calling code?